# How to build a GIMP plug-in with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gimp, gegl

I am going to develop an application for android using the GEGL library of GIMP. I am using visual studio 10. how to build the plugin with visual studio? what are the steps? how to run a GIMP project and debug?
I have also come across GIMPVS. please enlighten me about this.

Also, can anybody suggest any tutorial for developing APIs in C using GEGL library?

Comment: no Comment? Nobody interested in GIMP??? :)

Comment: +1 - Having trouble building Gimp plugins for Windows too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to be a bit more specific :)

When I compile GIMP plugins on windows, I simply download the libgimp headers and lib files from the gimp-win sourceforge project (they don't seem to be available for 2.6 though, try asking on the [GIMP irc](http://www.gimp.org/irc), download the gtk+ headers and libs from the [gtk+ site](http://www.gtk.org), and compile as I would compile any other program.

I guess you can do the same for GEGL, although you'd probably have to compile gegl yourself since I don't remember seeing any gegl distribution for windows. In order to compile GEGL, you will need

1. a mingw/msys environment
2. Binaries and Development headers of Gtk+ and [babl](http://www.gegl.org/babl/) (You may have to compile babl yourself).

You can refer to the [GEGL website](http://www.gegl.org) for instructions about that. Again, more details on what you are trying to achieve would help :) You can refer to my website on the page about [compiling gimp on windows](http://lightningismyname.blogspot.com/p/compiling-gimp.html), to find instructions which will help you compile gegl and friends on windows.

Comment: how to build the lib files for gegl? i am having the linking error. i have the .h files and also the .dll files from the GIMP directory. but how to get the .lib files?